# jquery - Get list item at position X

Tags: jquery, list

I have a comma seperated list

```
var list = 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Can I use jquery to get the value of list item 3 (for example)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll check the docs and let you know. Can Javascript work? list.split(',')[3] will return 4

Comment: I think you should edit your post to actually have valid Javascript. Is this a string i.e. `var list = '1,2,3,4,5,6'` or should it read `var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way of define a list in javascript should be

```
var i = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

after that, you can just retrieve the value using i[3], which is 4. You don't really need to use jQuery as javascript support it by default

Comment: Good point. Sometimes it can be easier to do "1,2,3,4,5,6".split(","). jQuery does this alot in its core.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think everyone was right. All the examples I tried worked

Answer (score 2):

jQuery... why not native javascript functions?

If your list is a string with a comma deliminator...

```
var list = "1,2,3,four,five,six";
var third = list.split(",")[2];
```

Otherwise..

```
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var third = list[2];
```

jQuery is moreso used for programability of DOM elements and data objects.

Comment: That would be the fourth item (arrays are 0-indexed, so 0 is the first item).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery. You could do it like:

```
 var item = list.split(',')[3]; //Gets 4th item
```

**Edit**

As other people have pointed out below, it might be better to have the list in an array in the first place.

```
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
//Rather than
var list = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
```

Although having it as a string then splitting does have some benefits:

```
var list = '1,2,3,4,5,6'.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use jQuery for this.You can do something like that;

```
var myArray=["1","2","3"];
```

and get value with `myArray[i]`